# unable to build xcode4.3 because getting command failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to develop iphone and phonegap also. Now I wants to create iphone app using **Phonegap**. So I installed **Phonegap 2.0** in my lion mac. Now I want to run the **UIWebView** using phonegap. I have followed this link for [my guidelines](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html):

When I run the project I got the below error in XCode 4.3:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '--DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1'
Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I have attached the screen shot of the error.

[image]

[image]

Please help me to solve the issue and run UIWebview in phonegap 2.0 CordovaLib.

Comment: Your post refers to a link that I don't see in the post, just FYI

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please see my Update question. Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: You did follow steps 22-25 of the guide?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I followed. But (libCordova.a) added with red line.

Comment: Sir, I followed "http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS"

Comment: Sorry sir, Now i am not getting any error but the xcode will not run. It shows build failed. Please help to solve the proplem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is

```
clang: error: unsupported option '--DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1'
```

which should be `-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1`

go to the build settings, search of "other c flags"/"other c++ flags", and change `--DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1` to `-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1`